# CREATE TABLE LIKE in DB2 10 for z/OS throwing an error

Tags: db2, zos, db2-zos

Using DB2 for z/OS v.10, I'm getting an error when I specify a tablespace when using CREATE TABLE ... LIKE.

I can successfully use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE if I don't specify a new tablespace, but it throws an error when I specify a tablespace. The manual seems to say that this should work, but I must have an error in the syntax.

```
Create Table MySchema.Deleteme2
  Like MySchema.Deleteme;

Table MYSCHEMA.DELETEME2 created.

Create Table MySchema.Deleteme2
  Like MySchema.Deleteme
    in MYDB.SOMETS
;

THE STATEMENT COULD NOT BE PROCESSED BECAUSE ONE OR MORE IMPLICITLY CREATED OBJECTS ARE INVOLVED 1.
```

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Dave

Comment: Note that I did drop the table between the two CREATE's.

Comment: Has the target tablespace already been correctly created with appropriate attributes and permissions?

Comment: @mao, thanks for your comment! I checked the target tablespace, and it does exist. Since your comment got me to thinking more, I manually created another tablespace, and the previously-described CREATE TABLE ... LIKE statement worked beautifully with the newly-created one. Therefore, I'm guessing that the attributes of the original tablespace are not compatible with this new table. Perfect! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by ensuring that the target tablespace was first created with the correct attributes and permissions, before running the `create table .... like ... in ...`